# date format : get the last and the first day in the month-sql-DB2

Tags: sql

how i can  write the following date with date function.. IN  **DB2**

```
 L2.FOM >= '2015-08-01' // the first day of the current Month 
 L2.TOM <= '2015-08-31'   // the last day of the current  Month
```

i tried  this  but it doesnot work

```
 L2.FOM=DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,CURRENT DATE), 0)   //for the first day of the month
```

Comment: There are many different forms, all of them depending on your rdbms. Can you tag your question with it?

Comment: first google result: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-date-functions/sql-server-eomonth-function/ . The first day of the month is always the first, so use month() and year(). For the last day, check if eomonth is availbale or you can also substract one day from the first day of the next month: add one month, take the first day of the month, and then substract one day.

Comment: You really have to tell us what SQL dialect you are working in (as @JaimeDrq pointed out). A general yet complicated solution is to take the first day of a new month and "subtract" one day, which is done differently in different SQL dialects.

Answer (score 1):

last date

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '12/1/2011';  
SELECT EOMONTH ( @date ) AS Result;  
GO
```

first date - is known to start from 1.
but here it is for name sake.

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @date), 0) AS StartOfMonth
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like SQL Server.

In that database, I would suggest using [`eomonth()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select eomonth(getdate()) as last_date_of_month,
       dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(getdate(), -1)) as first_date_of_month
```

For the first date of the month, I also often use:

```
datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
```